# Unexpected connection reset when bridging mosquitto broker with Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure-iot-hub, mosquitto, bridge

I am trying to create a bridge with Azure IoT Hub.
The configuration of mosquitto bridge is following:

```
connection Azure
address <my_hub_name>.azure-devices.net:8883

# error | information | notice | warning | all | debug
log_dest stdout
log_type all

## Auth Info
remote_username <my_hub_name>.azure-devices.net/<my_dev_name>/?api-version=2018-06-30
remote_password <SAS>
remote_clientid <my_dev_name>
bridge_cafile cert.pem

## some config
try_private false
cleansession true
start_type automatic
bridge_insecure false
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
bridge_tls_version tlsv1.2
notifications false

## Topics
topic devices/<my_dev_name>/messages/events/# out
```

And I get the following output:

```
Opening ipv6 listen socket on port 1883.
Bridge local.<my_dev_name> doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic devices/<my_dev_name>/messages/events/#
Connecting bridge Azure (<my_hub_name>.azure-devices.net:8883)
Bridge <my_dev_name> sending CONNECT
Received CONNACK on connection local.<my_dev_name>.
Bridge local.<my_dev_name> sending UNSUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: devices/<my_dev_name>/messages/events/#)
Received UNSUBACK from local.<my_dev_name>
Socket error on client local.<my_dev_name>, disconnecting.
Bridge local.<my_dev_name> doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic devices/<my_dev_name>/messages/events/#
Connecting bridge Azure (<my_hub_name>.azure-devices.net:8883)
Bridge <my_dev_name> sending CONNECT
Received CONNACK on connection local.<my_dev_name>.
Bridge local.<my_dev_name> sending UNSUBSCRIBE (Mid: 1, Topic: devices/<my_dev_name>/messages/events/#)
Received UNSUBACK from local.<my_dev_name>
Socket error on client local.<my_dev_name>, disconnecting.
...
```

Wireshark shows that for unknown reason Azure sends me a packet with FIN bit set, which results into connection reset.

At the same time mosquitto_pub is able to send a packet with same parameters (host, username, password). The utility mosquitto_sub also works without errors, but does not receive any of messages published by mosquitto_pub.

Spent several days trying to figure out the correct configuration without any success (including, of course, search on stackoverflow). I will be very appreciated for any hints.

As far as I know, nobody could connect to our IoT Hub before, so probably there maybe an issue with created hub. Unfortunately, learn.microsoft.com looks more like a quest rather than a help.
EDITED: corrected the topic parameter in configuration from "in" to "out".

Comment: Mmmh aren't you looking at an "out" bridge, instead of "in", for the devices/<my_dev_name>/messages/events/ topic? I.e. I would assume you want messages published to your Mosquitto broker to be propagated to IoT Hub?

Comment: yeah, the messages/events topic needs to be an 'out'  (forwarding out 'towards' ioT Hub)...   example here ->  http://busbyland.com/mosquitto-mqtt-broker-to-iot-hub-iot-edge/

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is left from my experiments. Anyway, this does not solve the problem. I have changed from "in" to "out" and behavior is the same as described - unexpected connection reset.

Comment: The problem is finally found: there was another broker which was bridging with the IoT Hub in a infinite loop. After stopping it, my broker successfully bridged with IoT Hub.
But there still is one problem: when I try to publish something into topic
```devices/<my_dev_name>/messages/events/foobar```
I get that annoying connection reset for the broker. So, the problem is solved, but partially. There is no value of broker which disconnects after each publication without message replication. :-/

Comment: The second problem is also solved: direct publishing into IoT Hub when bridge is working breaks the bridge. Publishing over bridge works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As inferred from the comments.

The problem will be that the 2 bridges will have generated the same client id.

Client IDs need to be unique across all clients connected to the broker. If a second client connects with the same client id the spec says the broker must disconnect the fist one.

The disconnected client then tries to reconnect and this results in the other broker being kicked off, which then starts a feedback loop with each client kicking the other off as it reconnects.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all connection errors were resolved by accurate setup of certificate and broker configuration. Except one and its description follows.
We create a bridge with above credentials (certificate, SAS login/password/clientid) - everything works fine.
The bridge is configured with following topic rule:

`topic # both 0 /devices/ devices/<my_dev_name>/messages/events/`

If I publish the following to my local broker:

```
mosquitto_pub \
    -h 10.0.2.15 -p 1883 \
    -t "/devices/foobar" \
    -m "{\"foo\" : \"bar\"}" \
    -d
```

everything is fine. But if I publish a bit more long topic

```
mosquitto_pub \
    -h 10.0.2.15 -p 1883 \
    -t "/devices/foo/foobar" \
    -m "{\"foo\" : \"bar\"}" \
    -d
```

I get connection reset error:

```
1607623721: Received PUBLISH from mosq-52yqOrz6C6riwvUUF3 (d0, q0, r0, m0, '/devices/foo/foobar1', ... (16 bytes))
1607623721: Sending PUBLISH to local.<my_dev_name> (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'devices/<my_dev_name>/messages/events/foo/foobar1', ... (16 bytes))
1607623721: Received DISCONNECT from mosq-52yqOrz6C6riwvUUF3
1607623721: Client mosq-52yqOrz6C6riwvUUF3 disconnected.
1607623721: Socket error on client local.<my_dev_name>, disconnecting.
```

I do not understand why Azure disconnects my bridge. I can make about a hundred messages to the topic `/devices/foobar` in 2-3 seconds without any complaints, but only one message to `/devices/foo/foobar` results into immediate socket error.
Probably, there is some restriction, but I can not find any of them, except the total maximum number of messages during one day.